# Submitting package to CRAN: Warnings in devtools:vignette_build()

Tags: r, package, cran

I am planning to submit a package to CRAN. I have no errors, warnings, or notes in check(). However, I do have warnings in vignette_build(). These warnings are simply due to my example dataset having NAs for some rows, which get removed.

Is this something I should add a comment about to CRAN? Or, would that be something that they will not see and/or will not care about?

Comment: Only the CRAN team can answer that.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that adding a comment would not hurt?

Comment: Or ask them before you submit.